# Add image in d3.js timeline chart instead of points

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, scroll, zooming

I have a timeline chart on which i would like to place icons/images instead of points.

**Question 1**

I was able to add image but I need to add that dynamically based on the data.

```
g.selectAll(null)
 .data(temp)
 .enter()
 .append("image")
 .attr({'x':function(d){ console.log(d.x);return xScale(d.x); },
        'y':function(d){ return yScale(d.y); }
 })
 .attr("xlink:href", "Content/Images/1.png");
```

I have multiple images from 1.png to 21.png, so based on the input data I need to change the images.

How do I do so?

**Question 2**

Another issue is this is a timeline chart so when panning along the x-axis the image should also pan, but in my case it is static.

How to make my image pan along with x-axis?

I have added the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tony_Rockzz/vmom43yb/)

**Edit :**

Attached screenshot for second question

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about first question:

```
g.selectAll(null)
 .data(temp)
 .enter()
 .append("image")
 .attr('x',function(d){ return xScale(d.x); })
 .attr('y',function(d){ return yScale(d.y); })
 .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){
   return 'Content/Images/'+i+'.jpg'
 });
```

Last question：

when xScale change:

```
g.selectAll('image')
.attr('x',function(d){ return xScale(d.x); }))
```

this change your code:

```
function zoomed(){
        svg.select('.x-axis').call(xAxis)
        g.selectAll('image').attr('x',function(d){          
            return xScale(d.x); })
        // svg.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis)
```

}

Comment: When scrolling to the right the image appears beyond `y-axis` is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Attached screenshot for the same

Comment: The two ways:
1. you need the code to judge the position and hide when the boundary is over.
2. put image in a new SVG, which is the size and location of the coordinate axis (visual area).
I'm really sorry, my English is poor, so I use translation software.